# How to redirect the existing URL to new URL

Tags: html, amazon-s3

I have a simple html website and in app folder I have a file called application_14.apk now I have sent the download link of this application to my users, later I uploaded this apk on S3 bucket then I changed the anchor tag link to s3 link.

Now I want that whenever any user navigate to **https://app.starmarketingonline.com/app/application_14.apk**
it should not download the file and must redirect to this link
**https://attandence-bucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/applicationVersions/application.apk**

I have hosted this site on cPanel and it does not use any serverside language.

Attached below is my htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit


Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^app/application_14.apk$ https://attandence-bucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/applicationVersions/application.apk [R=301,L]
```

Please help me out.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html

Comment: you misunderstood my question, I want to redirect from html to s3, not from s3 to html

Comment: @EmadKhan Please [edit] your question to include the HTTP server you are using on "https://app.starmarketingonline.com/app/". Also describe if you use any server side scripts and/or applications to serve the requests on "https://app.starmarketingonline.com/app/"

Comment: https://ibb.co/xzj73Wv

Comment: https://ibb.co/LQkjM9j my htaccess file

Comment: `.htaccess` is an apache feature. Share the contents of your `.htaccess` in the question, with syntax highlighting, so we can see what you tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.